# How i can run a python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please, can someone provide me with the way to run this project in Python?
https://github.com/Spidy20/Smart_Resume_Analyser_App.git

I tried run it with Pycharm and vs

Comment: How exactly did you try to run it?

Comment: "Actually, I searched on YouTube and didn't find any solution or way, so I have not made any progress on it

Answer (score 0):

pip install -r requirements.txt
streamlit run App.py

more info in README.md
https://github.com/Spidy20/Smart_Resume_Analyser_App/blob/master/README.md

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).